# Why does League Two have more promotion places than the Championship and League One?

Tags: football

There's something I've always wondered regarding the Football League's structure:

- There are three teams promoted/relegated between the Premier League and the Championship;
- There are three teams promoted/relegated between the Championship and League One;
- But there are **four** teams promoted/relegated between Leagues One and Two.

This has been the case ever since the Football League was reorganised into four tiers in 1958-59. [Wikipedia vaguely refers to this extra promotion/relegation place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_League_Third_Division#As_a_single_Third_Division) as a "tradition", but offers no explanation as to how or why this tradition began. I've never been able to think of an obvious reason why promotion/relegation between Leagues One and Two should be out of step with the leagues above them.

**Why does League Two offer more promotion places than the Championship or League One?** Is there a historical reason behind it, or was it determined arbitrarily?

Comment: Just a guess... since League One results from the merging of two regional leagues (North and South), they might used to have two relegations each. After the merging, they kept four relegations.

Comment: @Bebs That's a good guess, but there was no relegation from the Third Division North/South. The bottom-placed club in each would have to apply for re-election, and would be replaced if they failed.